# Difference between deployment and promotion terms in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, build, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

Are **deployment** and **promotion** interchangeable terms when referring to the process of building artefact in Jenkins, that is when merging
the code from GitHub to Jenkins pipeline to build, upload to Artifactory, start the Service in Dev environment and then when Jenkins moves that artifact from the Artifactory into other environments for example into test environment?

What is the difference between these 2 terms **deployment** and **promotion**? Is the promotion just a result of the deployment? What are the correct terms when referring to these 2 processes in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, in Jenkins, deployment refers to the process of deploying artifacts to staging, testing, or production environments using Jenkins or related tools and plugins. This involves deploying the artifacts to the application server.

Promotion, on the other hand, involves moving or copying artifacts from a testing environment to a non-production or production environment to avoid starting from scratch. After building, the artifacts are typically stored in a designated folder or repository called candidates, where they undergo testing. Once they successfully pass the testing phase, they are moved or promoted to a different folder or repository called releases, each of which has its own lifecycle policies.

In a previous company I worked for, we published or promoted artifacts between three different areas. For example, when building docker images, we published images to the docker-inprogress repository for each dev commit. Artifacts in this repository were only used for testing related to development, and were not promoted to any other area. For nightly builds, we published images to the docker-candidates repository, and once published, they were deployed to our application clusters. Based on the testing results, they were automatically promoted to the docker-releases repository. Artifacts in the in-progress repository remained there for 12 hours, while artifacts in the candidates repository remained for 30 days regardless of promotion. Artifacts in the releases repository remained indefinitely.

So from my understanding the terms deployment and promotion are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the application and the process you follow to take it up to production. Typically, deployment is the process of moving a build or release artifact to a particular environment, such as a development, staging or production environment. Deployment typically involves tasks such as transferring files, configuring settings, and starting the application or service.

Promotion, on the other hand, is the process of moving a build or release artifact from one environment to another, typically from a lower environment to a higher environment, such as moving from a development environment to a staging environment. Promotion usually involves additional testing and validation to ensure that the artifact works as expected in the new environment and that any necessary configuration changes are made. At a high-level following is the process flow.

[image]

Having said that, Promotion may involve a complete deployment process as well, where it would need to build and deploy artifacts. But this really depends on the process you follow at your organization.